# Looping over Cells and overwriting them if necessary in VBA

Tags: python, vba, excel

I'm trying to detect and process out "resets" in my data. The data should be increasing all the time, but sometimes the sensor likes to reset down to a much lower value. I want to detect these and rectify them by summing prior values with current value to get the current value.

Example:

```
1
2
5
10
11
100
150
2
3
5
```

Should be:

```
1
2
5
10
11
100
150
152
153
155
```

Here's a Python implementation that's worked for me:

```
def process(arr):
    max_before_reset = 0
    reset_detected = False
    old = arr[:]
    for i, e in enumerate(old): # enumerate contains original array
        if i == 0:
            continue
        if e < old[i-1]:
            print '\t', e, old[i-1]
            max_before_reset = arr[i-1]
            reset_detected = True
        if(reset_detected):
            arr[i] = old[i] + max_before_reset
            print old
    return arr
a = [97, 99, 100, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4, 3];
print process(a)
```

This needs to be done in VBA, so I took a shot at it:

```vb
Sub ProcessData_test(ByVal RawColumn As String, ByVal ProcessedColumn As String)
    Dim NumRows As Integer
    Dim MaxBeforeReset As Integer
    Dim ResetDetected As Boolean
    Const ps As String = "test2"
    Const rds As String = "test1"

    MaxBeforeReset = 0
    ResetDetected = False
    With Sheets(rds)
        NumRows = .Range(RawColumn & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    'MsgBox NumRows

    For i = 1 To NumRows
        If i = 1 Then
        Else
            If Worksheets(rds).Range(RawColumn & i).Value < Worksheets(rds).Range(RawColumn & i).Value Then
                MaxBeforeReset = Worksheets(ps).Range(ProcessedColumn & (i - 1)).Value
                ResetDetected = True
            End If
            If ResetDetected Then
                Worksheets(ps).Range(ProcessedColumn & i).Value = Worksheets(rds).Range(RawColumn & i).Value + MaxBeforeReset
            End If
        End If
        Next i
End Sub

Sub Test()
    Dim a As String, b As String
    a = "A"
    b = "A"
    Call ProcessData_test(a, b)
End Sub
```

But for some reason, it's not modifying the cells in the test2 sheet. I can't seem to figure out why. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you attempt to debug the VBA code step by step or at least add some more feedback using `Debug.Print` for example: `Debug.Print "For i = " & i & " rds value " & Worksheets(rds).Range(RawColumn & i).Value & " compared to " & Worksheets(rds).Range(RawColumn & i).Value` etc. If you place sufficient of these you can see if the code ever enters any `If` statement (or explain why not), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Simple typo:

your line (note that both sides of the < are the same)

```
If Worksheets(rds).Range(RawColumn & i).Value < _
   Worksheets(rds).Range(RawColumn & i).Value Then
```

should be

```
If Worksheets(rds).Range(RawColumn & i).Value < _
   Worksheets(rds).Range(RawColumn & i - 1).Value Then
```

Comment: This was definitely part of it. I got some help over on the excel subreddit that ended up being a proper solution. I'll post it as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

After @chris neilsen's typo, and with some work in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/4awg50/detecting_and_overwriting_resets_in_vba/d14460c), the final (working) script is here:

```
Sub ProcessData_test(ByVal RawColumn As String, ByVal ProcessedColumn As String)

    Dim NumRows As Integer
    Dim ResetValue As Integer

    Const ps As String = "test2"
    Const rds As String = "test1"

    With Sheets(rds)
        NumRows = .Range(RawColumn & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    'MsgBox NumRows
    ResetValue = 0
    'First Row
    Worksheets(ps).Range(ProcessedColumn & 1).Value = Worksheets(rds).Range(RawColumn & 1).Value

    'All other rows.
    For i = 2 To NumRows
        If Worksheets(rds).Range(RawColumn & i).Value >= Worksheets(rds).Range(RawColumn & i - 1).Value Then
            Worksheets(ps).Range(ProcessedColumn & i).Value = Worksheets(rds).Range(RawColumn & i).Value + ResetValue
        Else
            ResetValue = Worksheets(ps).Range(ProcessedColumn & i - 1).Value
            Worksheets(ps).Range(ProcessedColumn & i).Value = Worksheets(rds).Range(RawColumn & i).Value + ResetValue
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```